# MSSQL Count Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table like this in ms sql 2008:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| year |  JAN   |   FEB   |
+------+--------+---------+
| 2016 |  5K2   |   5K2   |
| 2016 |  5K2   |   5K2   |
| 2016 |  5K2   |   5K2   |
| 2016 |  8Z    |   8Z    |
| 2016 | R5205  |  R5205  |
| 2016 |  5K2   |   5K2   |
| 2016 |  5K2   |   5K2   |
| 2016 |  NULL  |   NULL  |
| 2016 |   TE   |   NULL  |
| 2016 |   TE   |   NULL  |
| 2016 |   8Z   |    8Z   |
+------+--------+---------+
```

And I want to get a count for each column, something like this

```
+------+--------+---------+
| opt  | JAN_cnt| FEB_cnt |
+------+--------+---------+
| 5K2  |   5    |   4     |
| 8Z   |   2    |   2     |
| R5205|   1    |   1     |
| TE   |   2    |   0     |
| NULL |   1    |   4     |
+------+--------+---------+
```

First, can this be done?  Second, how?  I have searched, but cant find exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Two questions: The first, have a table with all options? The second: Why NULL 1,4 instead of 1,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use `UNION ALL` with conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT s.opt,   
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.ind_from = 1 THEN 1 END) as jan_cnt,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.ind_from = 2 THEN 1 END) as feb_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT t1.jan as opt,1 as ind_from FROM YourTable t1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t2.feb,2 FROM YourTable t2) s
GROUP BY s.opt
```

Comment: Ops , typo :) @RichBenner

Comment: Looks great.  Quick question, what if feb has a value that jan doesnt, will it show up in the opt

Comment: Forget last comment.  It works.  One quick question.  What if i had values like PA, PA-5COS, PA-4AFG, etc and I wanted to count those together PA*, can I do that in this query?

Comment: Then you need to have another table with relations to know which value relate to which value something like `(PA,PA-5COS),(PA,PA),(PA,PA-4AFG)...` , then join to it and count by the first column

Answer (score 0):

I would advise putting the values into a different format:

- opt
- month
- cnt

You can do this as:

```
select opt, mon, count(*) as cnt
from ((select jan as opt, 'jan' as mon from t) union all
      (select feb as opt, 'feb' as mon from t)
     ) o
group by opt, mon;
```

It is easy enough to switch this to your format:

```
select opt, sum(jan) as jan, sum(feb) as feb
from ((select jan as opt, 1 as jan, 0 as feb from t) union all
      (select feb as opt, 0, 1, from t)
     ) o
group by opt;
```

I just prefer the first format.  It is easier to generalize to more columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.JAN, t2.FEB), t1.JAN_cnt, t2.FEB_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT JAN, COUNT(*) AS JAN_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY JAN
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT FEB, COUNT(*) AS FEB_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY FEB
) t2
    ON t1.JAN = t2.FEB
```